# Can't make progress bar working

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

Hi I've got a a challange were I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have an application that fetches data from a web service and imports it into a local database on the phone.

I have a class called `ConnectServer`. this class has a public method called `updatedata`. When using data in an activity I call the `ConnectServer.updatedata()` method to "fresh-up" the local database. Winthin the activity I'm doing the following:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",this.getText(R.string.txt_fetch_data), true);

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    try{
        ConnectServer.updatedata();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    dialog.dismiss();
    }
}.start();
```

Sofar so good. What I'm trying to acheive is that instead of the flat Dialog it shows a progress bar.

```
public class ConnectServer {
    public static String updatedata(Context _context){
        importData(callServer());
    } 
    private String callServer(){
      // https request to server returns JSON
    }

 private importData(String data){
     // loop thru data and insert / update local sqlite3 database
     //
     // TODO ----> update progress bar on each loop  <----
     //
}}
```

Please help. I've been spending hours to figure out how to do that

thanks

Comment: what problem u are getting any error :compile time or runtime plz if yes then plz add log with question

Answer (score 1):

Note that all UI calls must be running on the UI thread.

For example calls like `ProgressDialog.show` or `dialog.dismiss()`.
To make sure they run on UI thread, you can:

- Call those in UI handlers like `onCreate`, `onClick`...etc...
- Embedded those in `runOnUiThread`
- If you use a separate thread like it seems you are, use an ASyncTask and call those in `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

I made it work

```
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(AssetListActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle(getText(R.string.lbl_connecting));
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setProgress(0);
    dialog.setMax(0);
    dialog.show();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
    //update current gui after data is loaded
        updategui();}
    };
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        try{
        Looper.prepare();
        ConnectServer.updatedata(dialog);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        mHandler.post(r);
        dialog.dismiss();

        }
        }.start();
```

And within the ConnectServer class, callServer() method

```
                // vObject.getString("count") is the record count
            final int a = Integer.parseInt(vObject.getString("count"));
            if (dialog != null){
                Runnable task = new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                     dialog.setTitle(_context.getText(R.string.lbl_importing));
                     dialog.setMax(a);
                    }
                };
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(task);

            }
```